# Add class on click and disable mouseleave event?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have list of images with some simple `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` effect.
http://jsfiddle.net/4vTCr/

I would like to modify it in a following way:
when user click on particular image, its opacity should be set to 1 and `mouseleave` event should be disabled.

I was thinking to do it by adding a class `selected` on img `click` event. Then at the begining I can check if `img` has `selected` class. If yes then do not apply `mouseleave` event.
But I cannot deal with it. Could you give me some tips how to do it? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem pretty close to the answer, have a look at [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('.covers-sublist img').addClass('opacity').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.4});
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        $(this)
          .stop()
          .animate({opacity: 1})
          .addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: [Your solution works](http://jsfiddle.net/4vTCr/1/), but I wasn't precise when asking my question. I would like to remove opacity and disable `mousleleave` event only to image which was clicked last. Other images should have `mouseleave`/`mouseneter` events even they were clicked earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
This did the trick for me   

     $("#id").click(function(){
             $("#id").off("mouseleave");
        });

or $('#id').off('mouseleave mouseover');
```

and if anyone is wondering how to switch it back on(took me a while to figure out, as its not just like a switch, you have to repeat your code, so therefore I put my mouseover & mouseleave events in a function)

```
$('#id').click(function () {
            $('.class').on('mouseover', mouseoverEvents);
            $('.class).on('mouseleave', mouseleaveEvents);

        });
```

function mouseoverEvents() {

```
var origImg = ($(this).find('.imageUrl'));

if (origImg.is('img')) {
    Pixastic.process(origImg[0], 'blurfast', { amount: 1 });
}

$(this).find('.moreInfo, .addIcon').removeClass('displayNone');
$(this).find('.productText').height('100%');
$(this).find('.productText').stop().animate({ 'top': '-1.5vw' });
```

}

function mouseleaveEvents() {

```
var origImg = ($(this).find('.imageUrl'));

Pixastic.revert($(this).find('.imageUrl')[0]);

$(this).find('.productText').stop().animate({ 'top': '0' });
$(this).find('.moreInfo, .addIcon').addClass('displayNone');
```

}